# How can I speed up this Athena Query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am running a query through the Athena Query Editor on a table in the Glue Data Catalog and would like to understand why it takes so long to do a simple select * from this data.

Our data is stored in an S3 bucket that is partitioned by year/month/day/hour, with 80 snappy Parquet files per partition that are anywhere between 1 - 10 MB in size each. When I run the following query:

```
select stringA, stringB, timestampA, timestampB, bigintA, bigintB
from tableA
where year='2021' and month='2' and day = '2'
```

It scans 700MB but takes over 3 minutes to display the Athena results. I feel that we have already optimized the file format and partitioning for this data, and so I am unsure how else we can improve the performance if we're just trying to select this data out and display it in a tool like QuickSight.

Comment: 1-10MB is certainly not ideal, but at the same time it is not that much data that you actually need to optimize much. How long das a `count(*)` query take?

Comment: Right! The count(*) returns in 8 seconds. The count of rows is 33M, just for additional context.

Comment: I think unfortunately that simply is how athena works. Athena is slow and cannot really be used outside of explorative, manual queries. Do you actually need to retrieve all the rows, or would *some* rows suffice? At that point adding a `LIMIT 1000` should greatly reduce the runtime but of course you are not really sure what rows you will get and in what order, etc.

Comment: I guess you have already gone through https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/ - maybe the part about not over partitioning data might be interesting to you, maybe you do not actually need / want the hour partition.

Comment: Also: why does it only scan 700 mb? 80 files per partition but you query 24 partitions (one per hour) and each file being 1MB would already be 2GB. Compare that to the runtimes of the sample queries and the amount of data scanned and the runtime of 3 minutes is not that far off.

Comment: I have gone through that link, but thanks for mentioning it. You're right, I misstated the file sizes, they're closer to <1MB each. I am currently working in a dev environment, but once we move into production the data sizes per file will be more within the range I specified.

Comment: I think you're right, though. We probably do not need the hour partition given the file sizes. I think I'll try to repartition the data and rerun to see if that gives us any improvement and I'll let you know what I find. Thanks!

Comment: I tested repartitioning and removing the hour partition. The results showed an improvement in both runtime (14% reduction) and also data scanned (26% reduction) I assume due to snappy compression getting more gains on larger files. Thanks for the suggestion! Feel free to post it as answer if you'd like and I will accept it. (Unfortunately, the larger Athena query I was building benefitted from having Hour partitions and ran slower without them, so we ended up not going this route. But nonetheless, select * queries were sped up).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The select * performance was impacted by the number of files that needed to be scanned, which were all relatively small. Repartitioning and removing the hour partition resulted in an improvement in both runtime (14% reduction) and also data scanned (26% reduction) due to snappy compression getting more gains on larger files.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/